# Which is better: [intel-8080] or [8080]? Do we need both?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed that we have two very similar tags: [intel-8080](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intel-8080) and [8080](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/8080).

They are tagged on all the same questions (3 total by the same author, see [Are my questions about the 8080 family of processors and software on topic?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105)), have the same number of followers (2, probably the same people), and nearly have the *exact* same wiki!

I'm not sure which one should stay if they are duplicates. I don't like numeric-only tags because it's not immediately obvious what they're for, but this shouldn't be a problem once we get more wikis done.

We should pick one style of tags. These tags already exist:

- [8085](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/8085)
- [65816](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/65816)
- [6502](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/6502)
- [386](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/386) (AKA 80386, should it be renamed for constancy?)
- [80286](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/80286) (AKA 286, should it be renamed for constancy?)
- [6809](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/6809)

Also related (maybe?):

- [mos-6520](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mos-6520)
- [mos-6522](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mos-6522)
- [mos-6526](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mos-6526)

Answer (score 4):

You've got a good point about numbers, but I think in this realm people will actually be more familiar with [386](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/386) than they would with [80386](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/80386), and in that scenario I'd be hesitant to use [intel-386](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intel-386) unless it specifically referred to an Intel chip since in those days competing manufacturers could also make a chip called a 386.

While personally I associate [6502](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/6502) with [mos-6502](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mos-6502) I feel that those searching for information online are more likely to simply type '6502' into their search engine of choice.

In short, I feel like we should lean towards the the 'common' names for tags such as [68k](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/68k), [486](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/486) and [8080](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/8080) but use synonyms where appropriate, i.e. if a question is more specific to a vendor or particular model. A case of that would be using [68030](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/68030) instead of [68k](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/68k) if you were interested in the details of the 68030's instruction cache.

Comment: I think you make some good points, but you're missing some important things about the tag system/SEO. I think that having the keywords in the title is better for SEO; the most popular tag is added automatically to the title if it isn't already there. Tags are mostly a way of organizing things when on the site. It is important to weigh if it will inhibit the search/categorization ability on the site to have more/less granular tag categories.

Comment: Good point on the 386 clones: Wikipedia lists four designs, from five manufacturers.

Comment: Should we use synonyms?

Comment: I think they're useful for 'collecting' questions that get tagged wrongly. 6502 and mos-6502 feel like a good candidate for synonyms, but not 368 and intel-386.

Comment: @LaceySnr We **do** have a separate intel tag... Would it be practical to replace [intel-386] with [intel] and [386]?

Comment: Yeah that seems logical to me. Good call @Laurel!

Comment: @LaceySnr `6502` captures `mos-6502` by substring match, though...

Comment: _"A case of that would be using 68030 instead of 68k"_ Which then again opens the question of generc vs. specific tags, as it is (as of now) unwanted to have overlaping tags.

Answer (score 1):

I just asked a question about the 8080. My tag choices were [8080](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/8080) and [intel-8080](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intel-8080). I chose the later because it's more informative. Wikipedia calls it the [Intel 8080](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8080).

As of writing, when you type `80`, the suggestions are z**80**, **80**80, atari-**80**0, motorola-6**80**00 and **80**286, so having more specific tags will not hinder finding the right tags. Note that the tags are **80**286, but just 386. **80**386 is mentioned in that tag's description, but the descriptions do not get searched in.

I would support tags such as [zilog-z80](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zilog-z80) and [z80-clone](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/z80-clone) to differentiate between the standard chip and specifically non-standard chips.